# canvas.js time series ploted wrong (from Dec to Jan)

Tags: html, canvas, plot, time-series

As you can see I am ploting KVA vs time in line chart (canvas.js), the problem is the data is plotted from Jan 14, 2019 to Feb 13 2018, but the actual data belongs to Dec 14, 2018 to Jan 14, 2019. Not sure if this is a bug in canvas.js or I am doing something wrong. How to fix.

```
var options = {
    zoomEnabled: true,
    animationEnabled: true,
    title: {
        text: selectedText
    },
    axisX:{
        title: "Timeline",
        gridThickness: 1
    },
    axisY: {
        title: "KVA",
        includeZero: false,
        lineThickness: 1

    },
    data: [{
        type: "line",
        dataPoints:dataPoints
        }]  // random data
};
```

My datapoints look like this

```
dataPoints.push({ x: new Date(2018,12,13,06,09,38), y: 384 }); 
dataPoints.push({ x: new Date(2018,12,13,06,12,46), y: 386 }); 
dataPoints.push({ x: new Date(2018,12,13,06,15,53), y: 379 }); 
dataPoints.push({ x: new Date(2018,12,13,06,19,02), y: 377 });
....
....
dataPoints.push({ x: new Date(2019,01,11,17,11,12), y: 632 }); 
dataPoints.push({ x: new Date(2019,01,11,17,13,35), y: 616 }); 
dataPoints.push({ x: new Date(2019,01,11,17,15,49), y: 614 });
```

How to fix?
[image: canva.js time series]

Answer (score 1):

My bad, the month should start from 0 index, not 1 index. The correct code is

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

           $str = str_replace(array(":"," "),"-", $row['datetime']);
           $t = explode("-", $str);
           $month = $t[1]-1;

           echo 'dataPoints.push({
                        x: new Date('.$t[0].','.$month.','.$t[2].','.$t[3].','.$t[4].'),
                        y: '.$row['KVA'].'
                    });';
                }
```

That is 1 must be subtracted from SQL Month to make it 0 index for JavaScript Date() to work correctly.